# Can't access ArgoCD UI that is in a VM with port forwarding set in vagrant file

Tags: kubernetes, vagrant, argocd

I have setup a kubernetes cluster with kubeadm with a 3 node vagrant setup. I have installed ArgoCD and when I use vagrant ssh into the kubemaster vm, I can run:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/argocd-server -n argocd 8080:443
```

And I can curl it in the ssh session successfully with:

```
curl -k https://localhost:8080
```

I have a static ip for the nodes with the master being 192.168.56.2, and a port forward set for that vm

```
config.vm.define "kubemaster" do |node|
    ...
    node.vm.network :private_network, ip: 192.168.56.2
    node.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
    ...
end
```

On the host I try to access ArgoCD UI in browser with:

```
https://localhost:8080
https://192.168.56.2:8080
```

And I get connection refused

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

The nodes are running ubuntu 22 and ufw is not enabled.
Im running on a Mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I needed to add the address flag to the port forwarding command

```
// from
kubectl port-forward svc/argocd-server -n argocd 8080:443

// to
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 svc/argocd-server -n argocd 8080:443
```

Comment: Thank you very much. you are a life saver. can you explain why this flag is needed

Comment: It allows access on all interfaces